# Not the Other One

Tags: crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/ykkf4jve)

**Across**
1. – up (motivates)
5. String instrument also known as the gamba
9. Japanese PM Shinzo
12. Warm coat
14. Writer Bombeck
15. Navy vessel, perhaps
16. Placement, *not* making indecent suggestions
18. Lyricist Gershwin
19. Set up
20. With great foresight, *not* subject to change
22. Down in the dumps
23. British actress Lupino
25. Period of rapid growth
26. Nothing, zero
27. Relatives, familiarly
30. Saying, proverb
33. Learning programs?
34. Fond of
35/36/37. Both sides of an issue, or what some answers here do *not* contain
38. Unit for measuring a nail or a TV
39. Begone!
40. Something to see at La Scala
42. Dog used for hunting, e.g. greyhound
44. When it's high, so are the expectations
45. The night is darkest just before –
46. Miner's raw material
47. Peak
50. Arrangement, *not* adaptation
54. Brid's nest and staghorn, say
56. Novel by Vladimir Nabokov
57. Workers employed for a limited time, *not* people alive at the same time
59. Abbreviation you might see next to a left-wing US politician
60. Film starring Al Pacino and Robert De Niro
61. Most freezing
62. Long period of time
63. Trees lining a nightmarish street?
64. Flying insects

**Down**
1. Asked, *not* suggested
2. Cartman of South Park
3. – on the back (congratulating)
4. What people do in St. Moritz
5. "I came", in Rome
6. Part of the eye
7. Printed collection
8. Protected pool of shallow water
9. Anatolia, by another name
10. Hamilton's killer
11. Online marketplace
12. Gibbons or bonobos, say
13. Filmmaker Ephron
17. The shape of a NASCAR track, typically
21. Observe, detect
24. Buy the farm
27. Help
28. Mediterranean summit
29. Help!
30. Florence's river
31. Exaggerated reenactment of real events
32. Hindu community
33. Army member?
35. Photograph, for short
36. Ventilate, *not* film starring Nicolas Cage
39. Polite and proper
40. Rower's tool
41. Introductory part
43. Wrap with bands of cloth
44. Irishman who sings, *not* free of charge
47. Rugby's "touchdowns"
48. Starting digits of binary numbers
49. Hey, listen!
50. One way to end a song
51. River on the Germany–Poland border
52. Muslim clergy member
53. Elects
55. Cleveland's lake
58. Tease

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Notes:

> As suggested by 35-37a, clues of the form "X , not Y" have answers matching X where adding PRO or CON would yield an answer matching Y instead.